# How to determine which rules were executed from external code?

Tags: drools

Is there any way to know what "then" blocks were executed without change anything, which is external, in the actions inside the then blocks, from external code?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an `AgendaEventListener` to your session and keep track of the `AfterMatchFiredEvents` that are executed.

```
ksession.addEventListener( new DefaultAgendaEventListener() {
    public void afterMatchFired(AfterMatchFiredEvent event) {
        super.afterMatchFired( event );
        //Keep track of the event object. You can get information
        //such as the name of the fired rule from this object. 
    }
});
```

Take a look at section `4.2.4.4 Event Model` in [Drools documentation manual.](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Beta1/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#KIERunningSection)

Hope it helps,

Comment: Am I able to get the names of multiple rules which their "when" clause met the conditions ?

Comment: Try yourself and see. Each time the action (then) part of a rule is executed, you will receive an `AfterMatchFiredEvent` instance in your listener.